# Sort a list by a key and sort another list in the same way as the first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

For example there are three lists:

```
unsorted_key = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p']
sorted_key = ['e', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 't', 'u', 'w', 'y']
ciphertext = [
              ['u', 't', 'x', 'e'],
              ['p', 'r', 'k', 'p'],
              ['v', 'n', 'x', 'a'],
              ['n', 'h', 'e', 'x'],
              ['x', 'h', 'm', 's'],
              ['l', 'x', 'c', 'x'],
              ['x', 'c', 'y', 'a'],
              ['t', 'u', 'o', 'x'],
              ['e', 'r', 'm', 'e'],
              ['y', 'y', 'e', 'x']
             ]
```

Is it possible to take the order of the sorted_key and sort it into the unsorted_key, and take the order of the ciphertext and sort it in an identical way?

When moving 'q' from sorted_key[4] to sorted_key[0], it should move ciphertext[4] to ciphertext[0].

- All three lists will always be of equal length.
- The sorted_key and unsorted_key will never have repeating elements.
- The sorted_key will always be a sorted version of unsorted_key.

I've been thinking about it and the only way I can think of would be to use a helper function to dynamically generate and return a lambda function from the order of unsorted_key, and then use something like:

```
sorted_key, ciphertext = (list(i) for i in zip(*sorted(zip(sorted_key, ciphertext), key=generate(unsorted_key))))
```

But I really don't know how zip() or lambda functions work or how to make a custom sorting order into one, or if one can even be returned to be used in sorted(). I really can't seem to wrap my head around this problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It appears that `x` does not occur in `unsorted_key`, but does exist in the last row of `ciphertext`. How should missing elements be sorted?

Comment: it should move `ciphertext[4]` to `ciphertext[0]` - those are _lists_ - not characters ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner `'x'` is a character inside an element (a list) of ciphertext. ciphertext is just a list, in this example it happens to be a list of lists, but it could be a list of anything, it's the order of the elements inside ciphertext that matter, not the inner order of the elements themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient approach to solve this problem in linear time is to create a dict that maps keys to indices of `sorted_key`, and then create a mappping dict that maps indices of `unsorted_key` to indices of `sorted_key` based on the same keys, so that you can iterate an index through the range of length of `ciphertext` to generate a list in the mapped order:

```
order = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(sorted_key)))
mapping = {i: order[k] for i, k in enumerate(unsorted_key)}
print([ciphertext[mapping[i]] for i in range(len(ciphertext))])
```

This outputs:

```
[['x', 'h', 'm', 's'], ['e', 'r', 'm', 'e'], ['u', 't', 'x', 'e'], ['l', 'x', 'c', 'x'], ['x', 'c', 'y', 'a'], ['y', 'y', 'e', 'x'], ['t', 'u', 'o', 'x'], ['p', 'r', 'k', 'p'], ['v', 'n', 'x', 'a'], ['n', 'h', 'e', 'x']]
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know much about the different complexity of python functions and data structures but yours is probably the fastest here since you even considered the time complexity at all. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get the point, but...

First determine the moves (can be the opposite, it0s not clear to me):

```
moves = [ [i, sorted_key.index(c)] for i, c in enumerate(unsorted_key) ]
#=> [[0, 4], [1, 8], [2, 0], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 9], [6, 7], [7, 1], [8, 2], [9, 3]]
```

Maybe swap elements in `[i, sorted_key.index(c)]`.

Apply the moves to a receiver (`res`):

```
res = [ None for _ in range(len(ciphertext))]
for a, b in moves:
  res[a] = ciphertext[b]
```

So the output should be:

```
for line in res:
  print(line)

# ['x', 'h', 'm', 's']
# ['e', 'r', 'm', 'e']
# ['u', 't', 'x', 'e']
# ['l', 'x', 'c', 'x']
# ['x', 'c', 'y', 'a']
# ['y', 'y', 'e', 'x']
# ['t', 'u', 'o', 'x']
# ['p', 'r', 'k', 'p']
# ['v', 'n', 'x', 'a']
# ['n', 'h', 'e', 'x']
```

---

**For testing execution time**

```
import timeit, functools

def custom_sort(ciphertext, sorted_key, unsorted_key):
  return [ ciphertext[b] for _, b in [ [i, sorted_key.index(c)] for i, c in enumerate(unsorted_key) ] ]


custom_sort = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(custom_sort, ciphertext, sorted_key, unsorted_key))

print(custom_sort.timeit(20000))
```

Comment: Thank you, for me this was the easiest to understand solution because you put it in terms of moves, which was how I was thinking about it originally.

Comment: Glad to help. It can be rewritten as one liner `[ ciphertext[b] for _, b in [ [i, sorted_key.index(c)] for i, c in enumerate(unsorted_key) ] ]`, but I decided to be clearer than shorter. If speed is a concern, I edited addeding a way to test it. There is the one liner, but you can do the same with any method.

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `sorted` with a custom key can do it for you:

```
sorted(ciphertext, key=lambda x: unsorted_key.index(sorted_key[ciphertext.index(x)]))
```

Output:

```
[['x', 'h', 'm', 's'], 
 ['e', 'r', 'm', 'e'], 
 ['u', 't', 'x', 'e'], 
 ['l', 'x', 'c', 'x'], 
 ['x', 'c', 'y', 'a'], 
 ['y', 'y', 'e', 'x'], 
 ['t', 'u', 'o', 'x'], 
 ['p', 'r', 'k', 'p'], 
 ['v', 'n', 'x', 'a'], 
 ['n', 'h', 'e', 'x']]
```

The lambda basically boils down to:

1. Find the current index
2. Find the value of current index in `sorted_key`
3. Find the index of `sorted_key` value in `unsorted_key`
4. Sort it

The one thing that I'm not clear about is why do you need to "sort" `sorted_key` if the end result is identical to `unsorted_key`? Just `sorted_key = unsorted_key[:]` is simple enough if that's the case.  But if you *really* need to sort `sorted_key` as well, you can do this (it would actually make the `lambda` simpler):

```
ciphertext, sorted_key = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(ciphertext, sorted_key), key=lambda x: unsorted_key.index(x[1]))))

ciphertext
[['x', 'h', 'm', 's'], 
 ['e', 'r', 'm', 'e'], 
 ['u', 't', 'x', 'e'], 
 ['l', 'x', 'c', 'x'], 
 ['x', 'c', 'y', 'a'], 
 ['y', 'y', 'e', 'x'], 
 ['t', 'u', 'o', 'x'], 
 ['p', 'r', 'k', 'p'], 
 ['v', 'n', 'x', 'a'], 
 ['n', 'h', 'e', 'x']]

sorted_key
['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p']
```

Comment: You're correct, I don't actually need any operations done on either of the keys, just the correct ciphertext is enough. Probably some unclear wording on my part when explaining the problem. Yours is definitely the most compact solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question properly, but if you're attempting to sort the unsorted key, and ensure that the ciphertexts are sorted accordingly, this should do what you want:

```
pairs = zip(unsorted_key, ciphertext)
sorted_key = []
sorted_ciphertexts = []
for t in sorted(pairs):
   sorted_key.append(t[0])
   sorted_ciphertexts.append(t[1])
```

I'm sure there's probably a more elegant way to do it, but this will ensure that the key and ciphertexts are placed at the same index.